Connect to Azure DevOps using Python with InteractiveBrowserCredential
I'm trying to read pull requests using the Azure DevOps Python API. I want to run something like this from the command line. The code below opens up a browser, but I don't know if I'm going about this the correct way. I can do this via PATs, but can't I just use a token I get from InteractiveBrowserCredential instead? I can't find a way to do this without at PAT. Variations of the code below all tend to fail with various permission errors that aren't terribly helpful. Any help would be appreciated.
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential

credentials = InteractiveBrowserCredential()
conn = Connection(base_url='https://dev.azure.com/xxxxx/', creds=BasicAuthentication('', credentials.get_token('?????')))
client = conn.clients.get_git_client()
result = client.get_pull_requests("my-test-repo")


If you want a way without PAT token, generate access token for DevOps API with InteractiveBrowserCredential and use requests module to call DevOps API like this https://i.imgur.com/DOvlfQx.png

You can generate token with InteractiveBrowserCredential in Python and call Azure DevOps API with it.
In my case, I used below sample python code to connect to Azure DevOps:
from azure.identity import InteractiveBrowserCredential
import requests

credentials = InteractiveBrowserCredential()
access_token = credentials.get_token('499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default').token

#print(access_token)
print()
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(access_token),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

# Make a request to Azure DevOps API
response = requests.get('https://dev.azure.com/orgname/_apis/git/repositories/repoID/pullRequests?api-version=7.1-preview.1', headers=headers)
print(response.json())

When I ran above code, it asked me sign in with below screen to pick user account like this:

It displayed below page saying "Authentication complete" after successful authentication like this:

When I checked the console now, I got the response with pull requests details as below:

Reference:
How to access azure devops apis via an azure app? - Stack Overflow by me

Thanks, that works. Is there a way to not use the '.default' scope here? It would be ideal if I could get a token that could only do read-only operations.

Instead of /.default, you can specify that specific permission in scope like this 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/vso.work

Thanks. For whatever reason, the only way I can get a token via 'get_token' is by using the '.default' scope. Do you know what individual scopes are necessary?

That differs based on your requirements. Could you please post a new question with more details regarding this and comment the question link here?

New question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78336900/azure-devops-python-correct-scopes-for-getting-a-token

I added answer to your new question. Please check and let me know if it works :)
